# не проверяется условие равенства строк в python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, bash, subprocess

Стоит задача проверки существования директории, и если ее не существует, то создать. Я выполняю следующий код:

```
output = subprocess.run(["bash", "-c", "test -d " + "dir" + " && echo yes || echo no"],
                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out = output.stdout.decode("utf-8")
print(out)

if out == "no":
    print("create dir")
else:
    print("dir exist")
```

Но не зависимо от результата выполнения скрипта, я всегда попадаю во вторую ветку. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Нужно вывести `print(repr(out))`, и посмотреть что там на самом деле. Возможно там в конце перенос строки или еще что-то в этом роде. А вообще можно создавать директории средствами Python с помощью `os.makedirs()`

Comment: ну точно, там символ новой строки, а я целый день голову ломаю над этим. Спасибо, добрый ты человек

Comment: *На любом языке можно писать на shell*... :-(